# Is there a way to increase the width of the command palette in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When searching for a type, ctrl-t, the width is not sufficient to read the full path for a given type. Thats why I thought it could help to increase the palette size. But I did not find a tool that allows that. Anybody, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I started using be5invis.vscode-custom-css (https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) which is quite similar to CustomizeUI and also requires admin privileges to change a globally installed VsCode.

The most important feature: It is compatible with VSCode >= 1.58

Here is the content of the file I am importing with `vscode_custom_css.imports`:

```
.quick-input-widget {
    width: 80% !important;
    max-width: 1400px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
    margin-left: unset !important;
}
```

Now I have a wider command palette available.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing, there's a request to add it but there's a work-around if you have the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension installed.  See [the issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85374), specifically [this part](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85374#issuecomment-629982777).  Below is what I went with

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {    
     ".quick-input-widget": "width: 75% !important;  left: 25%;"
},
```

Comment: this no longer works: https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156 